# Is it possible to reverse multiple pow() functions?

Tags: php, math, reverse, pow

I'm wondering if it's possible to reverse calculations containing **multiple `pow()`** functions, with different (but known) exponents. Given the forward calculation, I need the reverse calculation.

```
<?php
# Forward calculation
$in = 9;
$out = pow($in, 2) + pow($in, 3); // = 810

# My attempt at an reverse calculation
$result = pow($out, 1/2) + pow($out, 1/3); // = 37.7821...
```

I want the reverse `$result` to be **9**, but seeing 37.7821... Which seems to be because `$out` needs to be divided among each `pow()` function, but unless the exponents are the same I'm not sure how to distribute that. As individually each pow() reverse works, but not when added together.

My goal in the end is to reverse a 4th order polynomial curve. I'm mostly self taught in maths, so prefer code examples to equations.

Comment: try to check the `log()` function : http://php.net/manual/en/function.log.php

Comment: In general, no. Even a cubic equation like the example above is no mean feat to solve analytically. You could however use an iterative solving approach, e.g. bisection, Newton-Raphson, secant methods.

Comment: Cubic polynomials can be solved analytically just fine (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Algebraic_solution)). Quartic polynomials also have an analytic solution but they are rather hard to calculate (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Solving_a_quartic_equation)), so an iterative approach like meow suggested is probably better. For higher-order polynomials, there is no analytic solution.

Comment: Are there any constraints on `$in`?  Is it an integer?  is it bounded within a range?  Might suggest a binary search for `$in` given `$out` and knowledge of its computation...but that's only if the domain of `$in` is too large to store a partial function of the inverse computation in a map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [meowgoesthedog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8204776/meowgoesthedog) and [Nico Schertler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1210053/nico-schertler) pointed out, it's not easy to solve this (At least far outside my expertise).

I've solved it by using curve fitting on data from the forward calculation ([mycurvefit.com](https://mycurvefit.com/)). It doesn't produce identical results, but close enough approximation for my use (point distribution for a leveling system).

Answer (score 0):

Let me call your first exponent `a` and second exponent `b`.

The `$out` contains `$in` in the following ratio -

```
1:[$in^(b-a)]
```

The ratio was formed by reducing the common factor in both the terms of `$out`.

So you can can modify your `$result` to only include the component of `$out` of the ratio from above -

```
$result = pow($out*[1/(1+$in^(b-a))], 1/2) + pow($out*[$in^(b-a)/(1+$in^(b-a))], 1/3); 
//the above $result will be 9 in the specific case
```

The value of `$result` will equal `$in`

Comment: OP wants to recompute the value of `$in` from `$out`. This answer is circular.

Comment: How can you use `$in` on the right-hand side of the formula if it is supposed to calculate `$in` explicitly?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, for the reverse calculation `$in` is unknown. But your code does work. Learning some new things here, thank you.